# why is my image not showing in recyclerview?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, imageview, firebase-storage

I followed a tutorial on youtube on how to retrieve images and text from Firestore and display them in the RecyclerView. I'm using the Glide library to display captured images. I bind my image using this code:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: itemViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val produk=listOfItem[position]
    holder.kategori.text=produk.productCategory
    holder.berat.text=produk.productWeight.toString()

    //img
    Glide.with(context)
        .load(produk.productIcon)
        .into(holder.gambarBarang)

}
```

I try to use  FirebaseStorage references:

```
val storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()

    val gsReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(produk.productIcon.toString())

    Glide.with(context)
        .load(produk.productIcon)
        .into(holder.gambarBarang)
```

but that seems to make the situation even worse, i get this error:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.b1, PID: 8300
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The storage Uri could not be 
 parsed.
```

I also noticed that some of the images that I put in the imageView are not visible. Is this a result of the inserted image being too large? Anyone know how to solve it?

**Edit:** I try to log the produk.productIcon.toString() inside the onBindViewHolder, and get this:

```
D/TAG: com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask$TaskSnapshot@7e89f3c
    gggg
D/TAG: com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask$TaskSnapshot@213e98e
    gggg
D/TAG: com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask$TaskSnapshot@df9e78f
```

I think the UploadTask come from the code that i use for adding the image to Firebase Storage:

```
val filePathAndName="product_images/"+""+timeStamp
val storageReference=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().
getReference(filePathAndName)

        val uploadTask= storageReference.putFile(image_Uri!!)
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                val downloadUri = task.result
                val item = Item(
                    ""+firebaseAuth.uid,
                    timeStamp,
                    kategori,
                    berat_sampah.toDouble(),
                    deskripsi,
                    ""+downloadUri,
                )
                FirestoreClass().addItem(this@AddProductActivity, FirestoreClass().getCurrentUserID(),item)
                ClearData()
```

Is this code the cause of the error?

Comment: Are you able to access `produk.productIcon.toString()` Uri?

Comment: @Zain, yes i can access it

Comment: If you try to use `Log.d("TAG", produk.productWeight.toString())` inside onBindViewHolder, what's the output? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo, I've added the log results in the edit section above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on @Abdullah Z Khan answer, i notice that the problem is with my image uri. I use task.getResult to get the uri, but it give me taskSnapShot instead.

Answer (score 1):

`produk.productIcon` is not an URL, in fact, it is a `UploadTask.TaskSnapshot` which is why it can neither be parsed as a storage reference nor as an image URL. While I don't yet understand where you are getting the UploadTask from(it's best if you make the changes there), I'd suggest you use [getDownloadUrl](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference#public-taskuri-getdownloadurl) to get a `Task` which will give you the URL you need to pass to `Glide`.
This is how it should look:

```
val storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()

storage.getReference(YOUR_STORAGE_PATH).getDownloadUrl()    
    .addOnSuccessListener(OnSuccessListener() {
    // onSuccess method call
        Glide.with(context)
            .load(URL FROM LISTENER)
            .into(holder.gambarBarang)
    }
)
```

Comment: well, the UploadTask comes from my code which is in charge of adding documents to Firestore. Does that mean I uploaded the wrong image uri to Firestore?

Comment: The provided snippet looks okay, so I'm not entirely sure. As far as I can understand, the putFile snapshot does not have a result value as specified here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/UploadTask.TaskSnapshot so there maybe in some way the actual task is being set as the value. Can you provide the Item class?